# Skype sent messages I didn't send

Tags: malware, skype

On my laptop, I played a video on YouTube. In the morning I looked on my Android phone and discovered that the video had been sent, in Skype, to about six of my contacts.

I'm not sure if the sending occurred from my phone or the laptop, but it's more likely from the phone for two reasons: I'm pretty sure the laptop was off, and my phone has been acting a little erratically. On the other hand, I didn't play the video while on my phone.

1) Is there a way to confirm which device sent the video?

2) How can I recall, unsend, or delete the video from the chats? If (on the phone) I select and hold the message, the pop-up menu does not include "edit" or "delete".

3) Does this sound like malware behavior? I'm scanning with "Lookout" but is that the best type for this type of thing?